# paypal rest sdk, Ruby, redirect error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paypal

All, I am trying to use the PayPal API, namely 'paypal-sdk-rest', in order to facilitate a transaction. I installed the gem, signed up for API credentials, and have edited the config/locales/paypal.yml, as to read:

```
# Credentials for REST APIs
client_id: myClientID
client_secret: myCLient Secret
# Mode can be 'live' or 'sandbox'
mode: sandbox

# Credentials for Classic APIs -- left these DF, I don't think it matters for this?
app_id: APP-80W284485P519543T
username: jb-us-seller_api1.paypal.com
password: WX4WTU3S8MY44S7F
signature: AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31A7yDhhsPUU2XhtMoZXsWHFxu-RWy
# # With Certificate
# cert_path: "config/cert_key.pem"
sandbox_email_address: Platform.sdk.seller@gmail.com

# # IP Address
# ip_address: 127.0.0.1
# # HTTP Proxy
# http_proxy: http://proxy-ipaddress:3129/

development:
<<: *default

production:
<<: *default
mode: live
```

My controller reads:

```
def pay
    Item.pay(user.email, item.price)
end
```

It passes the relevant information to by Item.rb model, pay function:

```
    def Item.pay(receiver, amount)

    require 'paypal-sdk-rest'
    include PayPal::SDK::REST
    include PayPal::SDK::Core::Logging

    # ###Payment
    # A Payment Resource; create one using
    # the above types and intent as 'sale'
    @payment = Payment.new({
        :intent =>  "sale",

        # ###Payer
        # A resource representing a Payer that funds a payment
        # Payment Method as 'paypal'
        :payer =>  {
            :payment_method =>  "paypal" },

        # ###Redirect URLs
        :redirect_urls => {
            :return_url => "http://localhost:3000/payment/execute",
            :cancel_url => "http://localhost:3000/" },

        # ###Transaction
        # A transaction defines the contract of a
        # payment - what is the payment for and who
        # is fulfilling it.
        :transactions =>  [{
            # Item List
            #:item_list => {
                #:items => [{
                    #:name => "item",
                    #:sku => "item",
                    #:price => "5",
                    #:currency => "USD",
                    #:quantity => 1 }]},
            # ###Amount
            # Let's you specify a payment amount.
            :amount =>  {
                :total =>  amount
                :currency =>  "USD" },
            :description =>  "This is the payment transaction description." }]})

    # Create Payment and return status
    if @payment.create
    # Redirect the user to given approval url
        @redirect_url = @payment.links.find{|v| v.method == "REDIRECT" }.href
        logger.info "Payment[#{@payment.id}]"
        logger.info "Redirect: #{@redirect_url}"
    else
        logger.error @payment.error.inspect
    end
end
```

When I execute, all seems to go well. My debugger seems to indicate that the @payment object is created:

```
Started GET "/items/16/pay" for ::1 at 2016-07-22 11:38:01 -0400
Processing by ItemsController#pay as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"16"}
PayPal-Request-Id: d1882bd1-482c-4110-9a4f-00b60286be46
Request[post]: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment
Request.body={"intent":"sale","payer":  
{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount":
{"currency":"USD","total":"5"},"description":"This is the payment transaction 
description."}],"redirect_urls":      
{"return_url":"http://localhost:3000/payment/execute",
"cancel_url":"http://localhost:3000/"}} request.header={"X-PAYPAL-SANDBOX-  
EMAIL-ADDRESS"=>"Platform.sdk.seller@gmail.com", "Authorization"=>"Bearer 
A101.JVwZ4_AQ3l56GDFxY7gMuGhvEb5mcRLD-
1YVVfbVMzc4Hwhkny7_7HwZHy7oFV9O.xgwNiMdipUpIY5dWRF8qAM3ewTG", "Content-
Type"=>"application/json", "User-Agent"=>"PayPalSDK/PayPal-Ruby-SDK 1.4.8 
(paypal-sdk-core 1.4.8; ruby 2.2.2p95-x86_64-darwin14;OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 
2015)", "PayPal-Request-Id"=>"d1882bd1-482c-4110-9a4f-00b60286be46"}

Response[201]: Created, Duration: 0.798s
Response.body={"id":
"PAY 7X377846ES435831EK6JD3SA","intent":"sale","state":"created","payer":
{"payment_method":"paypal"},"transactions":[{"amount": 
{"total":"5.00","currency":"USD"},"description":"This is the payment 
transaction description.","related_resources":[]}],"create_time":"2016-07-
22T15:37:43Z","links":
[{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-
7X377846ES435831EK6JD3SA","rel":"self","method":"GET"},
{"href":"https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-
checkout&token=EC-
2LT140537P6103026","rel":"approval_url","method":"REDIRECT"},
{"href":"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-
7X377846ES435831EK6JD3SA/execute","rel":"execute","method":"POST"}]}        
Response.header={"date"=>["Fri, 22 Jul 2016 15:37:43 GMT"], "server"=>
["Apache"], "proxy_server_info"=>
["host=slcsbplatformapiserv3002.slc.paypal.com;threadId=443"], "paypal-debug-
id"=>["5900d3ddac5b2", "5900d3ddac5b2"], "correlation-id"=>["5900d3ddac5b2"], 
"content-language"=>["*"], "set-cookie"=>["X-PP-SI         
=name%3DSANDBOX3.API.1%26silo_version%3D1880%26app%3Dplatformapiserv%26TIME%3D
3342701143%26HTTP_X_PP_AZ_LOCATOR%3D; Expires=Fri, 22 Jul 2016 16:07:44 GMT;   
domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly", "X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 
Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT"], "vary"=>["Authorization"], "content-length"=>["697"], 
"connection"=>["close"], "content-type"=>["application/json"]}

Payment[PAY-7X377846ES435831EK6JD3SA]
Redirect: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-  
checkout&token=EC-2LT140537P6103026

Rendered items/pay.html.haml within layouts/application (16.1ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 885ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I believe, therefore, that if @payment.create should == true, and that the user should be redirected to PayPal to complete the transaction. Instead, the user is directed to the view, items/pay.html. I imagine that the internal server error has something to do with it, but I am at a loss at the moment. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post the controller code please.

Comment: Added the controller code.

Comment: You aren't redirecting them anywhere, hence rails looking for the view.

Comment: I take it that I simply do a redirect_to @redirect_url

Comment: Yep, but you need to return `@redirect_url` from your pay method to your controller, but you will also need to handle the payment failing

Comment: Thank you!  Looks like I have @redirect_url working. I'm not sure where to start with the payment failing.  Can you explain what you mean?  Clearly, I will need a way to mark that the item has been paid for upon the return from the PayPal API, do you mean handle the error if the payment fails through PayPal?

Comment: If the payment fails, what does `Item.pay` return?  What should your site do?

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know yet, because I think I need to create a new route. 

It seems that I also have to create a /payment/execute route, but I don't see anything in the API doc about that.

Comment: So, I can now execute a payment and return to appropriate page. I am still unclear what 'Item.pay' would return if the payment fails.  What's more, I cannot really envision how a Payment would fail. Specifically, I believe that the PayPal interface would not permit a user to submit an invalid payment before redirect?  Still, I know that there is '.error' function for '@payment', so I am missing something.